# Eclipselink Multitenancy and Tenants Hierarchy (shared some data)

Tags: java, spring, struts, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I'm interested to use my **Java+Struts+Spring+EclipseLink** application with multitenancy, I did some examples to provide multitenancy and everthing was ok.
But...

I have a equirement that could be possible this situation:

- Tenants A,B,C with isolated data and shared schema and using single table.
- Tenant A and B can see also data from Tenant C. But Tenant C can see just its own data as multitenancy works normally.

A real example could be a company with differents deparments using my application but some departments can see other data.

For insert data I think I can manage my code with `@Multitenant(MultitenantType.SINGLE_TABLE)` but I dont't know if the part of filter data is possible to be managed with eclipseLink or what solution I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a different persistence unit for each tenant, and provide different configuration for each.

You could also not use @Multitenant but use @AdditionalCriteria instead, or application logic.